# RxJs multiple observables emitted from FileReader - collect as array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm building a filedrop platform, and hit an issue while reading Blob files from the FileReader API.
Code flow is: get files from user in the upload service as an observable array, and generate a base64 string from the blob, to display in the browser.

Reader:

```
  async getFileList(files: File[]) {
    let src!: IStoryFile[];
    for (const f of files) {
      const blob = await this.readFileBlob(f)
      src = [{ file: f, src: blob }]
    }
    this.uploadSrv.setFilesUpload(src);
  }

  readFileBlob(file: File): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, _) => {
      const reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onloadend = (e) => {
        resolve(reader.result)
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
  }
```

After resolving each of the files inside the forof, it will do a `next` to the service, that provides the final array for the DOM *ngFor | async loop:

```
protected files$!: Observable<IStoryFile[]>;
...
this.files$ = this.uploadSrv.getFilesUpload$()
      .pipe(
        tap(val => console.log(val)),
      )
```

What is the current results:
The function emits the array length of Observable values [image: as seen in this img]

What is the expected results:
The function will emit one single array of all objects, according to this interface:

```
export interface IStoryFile {
  file: File;
  src?: string | ArrayBuffer | null;
}
```

Comment: can you try using mergeMap operator to combine all the response observables

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why/how. The mergeMap is commonly used as the `.then()` method in promises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reinitializing `src` every time in `for-of` expression. Change this to `push`.

```js
  async getFileList(files: File[]) {
    let src!: IStoryFile[] = []; // Initialize
    for (const f of files) {
      const blob = await this.readFileBlob(f)
      src.push({ file: f, src: blob }); // Push new object
    }
    this.uploadSrv.setFilesUpload(src);
  }
```

Comment: Sometime's the most obvious issues, are the hardest to find :-) Thank you, friend!